# how to code sub query in mysql with join

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get data from two table on sub query.... I tried some queries but...
result was unknown
how to fetch data from two table with same id
i tried this.....I need to fetch record from two tables for lastlogin deatil and total login count.......................................................................................

```
SELECT 
  `name` uname,
  pwd,
  mob,
  dor,
  mob1,
  fld_point,
  fld_count,
  logindetail 
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
  FROM
    tbl_lastlogin_log 
  WHERE fld_userName = 'all') AS total_visits from fruser
WHERE uname = 'fruser'
```

Comment: What's the name of the two tables? one is `tbl_lastlogin_log` and the other?

Comment: Please hare your table structure for better understanding.

Comment: you are missing FROM `Table` in your main query, and post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table structure, But I can give you the structure what you need to use for joins. Here you go,

if you have two tables(table1, table2) and want to get some fields from those two tables. Then,

```
select table1.field1, table1.field2,table2.field1, table2.field2 from table1 inner join  table2 on table1.field1 = table2.field1 where table1.field1 = "value";
```

This will join those two tables(table1, table2) on that condition(table1.field1 = table2.field1). And from the result set, it'll filter with where condition(table1.field1="value").

Want to know more on SQL Joins, use this - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do. But you can try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
(select cc from another_table at where at.fld_userName = t.uname) as cc,
(select ccc from yet_another_table yat where yat.fld_userName = t.uname) as ccc
from table t
where uname = 'fruser';
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Saqueib you're missing a `FROM` in your query. I've prepared a fiddle to demonstrat the principle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99d67/3

Table `user`:

```
+-------------------+
| UANME | PASSWORD  |
+-------------------+
| userA | secretA   |
| userB | secretB   |
+-------------------+
```

Table `lastlogin`:

```
+----------+------------+
| USERNAME | DATE       |
+----------+------------+
| userA    | 2014-01-01 |
| userA    | 2014-01-02 |
| userA    | 2014-01-03 |
| userA    | 2014-01-04 |
| userB    | 2014-02-01 |
| userB    | 2014-02-10 |
+----------+------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT uname, (
               SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lastlogin WHERE username = uname
              ) AS logincount
FROM user;
```

Result:

```
+-------+------------+
| UNAME | LOGINCOUNT |
+-------+------------+
| userA | 4          |
| userB | 2          |
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have syntax error in query, your query is OK, no need for JOIN

```
SELECT 
  `name` uname,
   pwd,
   mob,
   dor,
   mob1,
   fld_point,
   fld_count,
   logindetail, //Here you missed the comma
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM tbl_lastlogin_log 
    WHERE fld_userName = 'all') AS total_visits 

FROM fruser
    WHERE uname = 'fruser'
```